# WPF Conditional Binding. Button.IsEnabled to SelectedIndex >= 0

Tags: wpf, data-binding, xaml, binding

I want to bind a buttons `IsEnabled` property to a condition like `myObject.SelectedIndex >= 0`. Is there a simple way to do this in the xaml (without having to do crazy things to any underlying objects)? I haven't really seen a good example.

Honestly, I wish this was as easy as Flex 3 ... I.E.:

```
<mx:Button enabled="{dataGrid.SelectedIndex >= 0}" ...
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

SelectedIndex is -1 if nothing's selected, right? Reverse your logic and use a trigger:

```
<Button ...>
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="enabled" Value="True" />

            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger
                    Binding="{Binding SelectedIndex,ElementName=dataGrid}"
                    Value="-1">

                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    <Button.Style>
<Button>
```

Comment: Thanks, I can use that for one of my buttons, but the other one would be where SelectedIndex >= 1. Can I do that like your sample above but just with a MultiDataTrigger?

Comment: MultiDataTrigger is used when the conditions are anded together. To do SelectedIndex>=1 copy the datatrigger for '-1' and change the trigger value to '0'.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't found a particularly easy-to-use way to embed an expression into XAML, so here's what I've been using instead:

```
BindingOperations.SetBinding(myBtn, Button.IsEnabledProperty, LambdaBinding.New(
    new Binding { Source = myObject,
                  Path = new PropertyPath(ComboBox.SelectedIndexProperty) },
    (int selectedIndex) => selectedIndex >= 0
));
```

You'll have to write this in C#, for example in the window's constructor.

This also works seamlessly for multi-sourced bindings:

```
BindingOperations.SetBinding(myBtn, Button.IsEnabledProperty, LambdaBinding.New(
    new Binding { Source = myObject,
                  Path = new PropertyPath(ComboBox.SelectedIndexProperty) },
    new Binding { Source = myObject2,
                  Path = new PropertyPath(Button.ActualHeightProperty) },
    (int selectedIndex, double height) => selectedIndex >= 0 && height > 10.5
));
```

Observe that the lambda is statically typed, and any type errors are (relatively) noisy, helping track them down. The lambda return type is also taken into account; you could use this to bind the width of one object to be a complex formula based on the width of another one...

This `LambdaBinding` class isn't built-in; you have to include the [LambdaBinding.cs](https://bitbucket.org/rstarkov/wpfcrutches/src/tip/LambdaBinding.cs) file.

**Side note.** It's a real shame that XAML doesn't allow expressions. Yes, I realise XAML is supposed to be "for designers" and free of this elusive thing we call *application logic*, but who are we kidding here... Firstly, the `DataTrigger` shown in the other answer is basically a conditional expression, and so no different (only *much* longer) than `{Binding source.SelectedIndex >= 0}`. Secondly, if the idea is simplicity, then the binding expressions that a designer is supposed to be able to write are far beyond the abilities of a non-programmer... if you need proof, consider something like this:

```
{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UIElement}, 
                                        AncestorLevel=1},
         Path=IsEnabled}
```